# Is there a way to stop GoogleTest after a specific test is run, whether it passes or fails?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, debugging, googletest

I have a large number of unit tests run through GoogleTest. Currently one of them (call it fooTest) is failing when the full test suite is run, but passing when run alone. So one (or more then one) of the tests that run before fooTest is doing something that causes it to fail, which of course is a big nono for testing and I obviously want to find the culprit.

This is happening with default run conditions, so the test order is always the same. The fooTest is about half way through this run order and there are enough tests that the run time of the second half of the tests is significant, especially if running things multiple times.

So I want to set googletest to always stop the test run after fooTest is run - whether it passes or fails. I know I can do --gtest_break_on_failure, but if I do a test run that causes fooTest to pass I still want to stop right there and not go through everything else. I could run with debug and add a breakpoint after the test, but that also slows things down a little and feels less then ideal.

It seems like this could be an simple setting, but I've not been able to find anything yet. I'm hoping there is either a parameter on run I can use, or a trick to make this happen.

Comment: Why can't you just call exit() function? https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/

Comment: Presumably you will also want to disable tests _before_ the failing test, perhaps to do a binary search for the offending test. How do you intend to do that? The solution to stop execution after the intermittently failing test won't help here. Maybe good old commenting out tests? Or some search/replace to prefix DISABLED_?

Comment: There is no such setting, because it's not useful afait. The normal workflow in such situation is to launch debugger and set breakpoint in the offending test.

Comment: Usually during the investigation of these kinds of issues I try to find a minimal test set to reproduce the issue: Just leave in the half of the tests run prior to your test that makes it fail and then repeatedly cut this test set in half until you've got a minimal set of test cases allowing you to reproduce the issue. You should be able to accompilish enabling/disabling the tests with the test filter (`--gtest_filter`) that can be passed as command line parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Simply call [exit](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) function at the end of `fooTest`.
2. Create a [test fixture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJqRlSTQlh4&t=1337s). In `SetUp` check for a flag that is always false, but it sets to true if `fooTest` is executed. Something like this:

```
bool skip_testing = false;

// Class for test fixture
class MyTestFixture : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  void SetUp() override {
    if (skip_testing) {
      GTEST_SKIP();
    }
  }
};

TEST_F(MyTestFixture, test1) {
  //
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

TEST_F(MyTestFixture, footest) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
  skip_testing = true;
}

TEST_F(MyTestFixture, test2) {
  //
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

TEST_F(MyTestFixture, test3) {
  //
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

See a working a working example here: https://godbolt.org/z/8dzKGE6Eh

3. Similar to Option 2, but use [explicit success and failure](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#success-failure) in `SetUp` instead of `GTEST_SKIP`. However using `GTEST_SKIP` is preferred, cause your output will show that the tests were skipped.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought about using exit(), think I was too focused on looking for a gtest solution and the simple option slipped my mind.